# Regex, get the rest of the unmatched string

Tags: c#, regex

My test String

"Example string 123 with example strings which have small words on the sea"

got a regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(?<tag>small|with)\b(?<param>.*)");
```

splitting the reuslt into two groups:

> G0=with, G1= example strings which have small words on the sea

G1 Not good , what I would like to see is

> G0=with, G1= Example string 123

Basically im trying to return 1st match and the string before teh 1 st match. But im getting the string after the 1st match

Does anyone see a mistake in my reg ex ?#

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to describe what you want (and us to understand) by posting the results you expect.

Comment: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Correct, Jerry - good point,I was in a rush. Should be more understandable now.

Comment: Dan, believe me I have a bunch of tools to test the regex.....

Comment: If your question is answered please mark the best answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Reply to your Question: `Regex, get the rest of the unmatched string`

**Simple**

```
string toSearchString = "your string here";

Match match = new Regex("*some pattern here*").Match(toSearchString );

string unmatchedString = toSearchString.Replace(match.Value,"");
```

So now you have the Unmatched String. you can have coffee!!

Note: `This answer is not relevant to the problem posted here but is relevant to the Question, This answer is for people who land up in this page seeking for fetching unmatched string`.

Comment: `Regex.Match` does not return all of the occurrences of a string, though `.Replace` removing all. Let `pattern="[0-9]*"` and `inputString = "34abc34"`. Match will be the first `34`, but the `unmatchedString` after replace will be `abc` with this technique(it should instead be `abc34`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<param>.*?)\b(?<tag>small|with)\b
```

which means swap positions of the capturing groups and make first group lazy using `?`.

Notice the swapped value of groups.

See [live example](http://rubular.com/r/s3h55KsRyD)

Comment: Wonderfull ! I totally forgot about matching pattern, You are the RegEx Gandolf !

Comment: Also - How would You make it to start matching from right to left ?

Comment: AFAIK, regex match is a substring of contiguous characters and if there is a match you can not capture something from behind the match upto some previous location. If with some way your able to do so, you will end up with a regex which have low performance due to backtracking. The greater the string the more it will backtrack.